# Fresh installation of sphinx-quickstart fails

Tags: python-sphinx

Trying to get it going with Sphinx for the first time, with a clean Sphinx 1.1.3 installation, and shinx-quickstart fails. Should there be any dependencies installed? I tried to `pip --force-reinstall sphinx` but the result is the same.

```
  myhost:doc anton$ sphinx-quickstart 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sphinx-quickstart", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Sphinx==1.1.3', 'console_scripts', 'sphinx-quickstart')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.1.3-py2.7.egg/sphinx/quickstart.py", line 19, in <module>
    from sphinx.util.osutil import make_filename
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.1.3-py2.7.egg/sphinx/util/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from docutils.utils import relative_path
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.9-py2.7.egg/docutils/utils/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from docutils.io import FileOutput
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.9-py2.7.egg/docutils/io.py", line 18, in <module>
    from docutils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.9-py2.7.egg/docutils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in <module>
    locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 496, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 428, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename

  ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is, but what happens if you do `import locale` and `print locale.getdefaultlocale()` in your python shell?

Comment: raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I was getting the same issue in Mac OS X Snow Leopard. It seems to be an issue with Terminal.app.

Please add the following to your $HOME/.bash_profile

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Do

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

and try. This will solve the issue.

Comment: Work even on OS X El Capitan.